Confusion about the local rank theorem and orientation reversing local diffeomorphisms
Say we are given a local diffeomorphism $F:M\rightarrow N$. By the local rank theorem, for each point $p\in M$ there exists a chart $(U,(x^i))$ around $p$ and a chart $(V,(y^i))$ around $F(p)$ so that $F(U)\subseteq V$ and so that, in those charts, $F(x^1,x^2,\cdots,x^n)=(x^1,x^2,\cdots,x^n)$. In those coordinates, the determinant of $dF_p$ is given by the determinant of the matrix $[\frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}(\hat{p})]_{1\leq i\leq n}$ (since this is the representation matrix of $dF_p$ with respect to $(\partial_{x^i}\vert_p)$ of $T_pM$ and the basis $(\partial_{y^i}\vert_{F(p)})$ of $T_{F(p)}N$). Now, $F^j=x^j$ so we get ones on the diagonal and $0$ everwhere else. So the determinant is $1$ in those two bases and, therefore, all bases.
Suppose now that $M$ and $N$ are oriented and connected and that $F$ is orientation reversing. Thus, it is not orientation preserving. So in any oriented charts of $M$ and $N$ its differential has nonpositive determinant. Since it is a local diffeomorphism $\det(dF_p)\neq 0$, which means that $\det(dF_p)<0$.

Can you elaborate a bit on how you get those determinants?

I added more details.


So the determinant is 1 in those two bases and, therefore, all bases.

This is only true if you change the bases in the domain and the coimage in a compatible way. So you have a linear map $F:M \rightarrow N$ between two $n$-dimensional spaces equipped with some bases. Then, the determinant remains invariant only if the change of basis matrix is the same in $M$ and $N.$ The most common case is $M=N,$ of course.
If you are allowed to change bases in $M$ and $N$ however you like (which basically what's happening when you are changing charts on your manifold) then it is an easy exercise to show that the only invariant of a matrix is its rank. The determinant is far from preserved.
